# Run Jmeter Test with Jmeter Dependency

Tags: java, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, web-api-testing

I have a bunch of Jmeter files (.jmx) which have a lot of tests inside them. I want to run these test without the dependency of jmeter. Is there a way to run jmx files directly in Java without having to download and install jmeter on the machine.

I tried StandardJMeterEngine but that requires jmeter on the machine and I don't want that. If there is any way to do it please tell me.

Comment: Provide source code

Comment: Sorry I am new, but which source code I just have a JMX file. I want to run it in java.Is there a way to convert this JMX file to rest assured or can I use jmeter gradle dependency so I don't have to download Jmeter.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm afraid you won't be able to run a JMeter test without JMeter installed, you will need to have at least [ApacheJMeter_core](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jmeter/ApacheJMeter_core) jar plus relevant plugins for the protocol(s) you're using in your tests in "your" Java project [classpath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html)

If you want JMeter installation process to happen automatically you can check out the following options:

1. [JMeter Maven Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-maven-plugin)
2. [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/) framework which has [JMeter Executor](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/)
3. Numerous [`jmeter` Docker images](https://hub.docker.com/search?q=jmeter)

Comment: What If I just download it in my system take the relevant jars ,containerise the jars and put give it to a separate system does the new system need to download Jmeter again?

Comment: Also If I use Gradle(I am using Gradle not Maven) dependency I don't need to download jmeter?